# Should I have a separate history.js for createBrowserHistory?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history, react-router-dom

Looking around people seem to be using `createBrowserHistory` in a separate `history.js` file and I am curious what is the exact reason to create a separate file for that.

What I am thinking of doing

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

class MySpecialComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.history = createBrowserHistory();
  }
}

<Router history={this.history}>
  <div>
    <Route
      path="/"
      render={() => <RootComponent />}
      exact
    />
    <Route path="/confirm" render={() => <ConfirmComponent />} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Is it a bad approach to have it inside a constructor and I should make a separate `history.js` containing something like:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

And import that file in the `MySpecialComponent`

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a dedicated file but you should statically create **one** instance for the whole application. Your app usually has only one history, not one for each component.

Comment: But as I understand current approach is creating one instance for the whole app, or no?

Comment: Only if you instanciate only one `MySpecialComponent` component and never unmount it. That may currently be the case but is not guaranteed to change later. The point is that there should only ever be that one history for the whole lifetime of the app. And to correctly express that you should statically initialise it outside of the component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I create a `history` object separately and not use the `BrowserRouter` is if I want to do `history.push` or `history.replace` in some place when I don't have access to the router props.
Now if I create the history as a property of a component I can't import that `history` object in other files.
So I make a separate `history.js` and then I can import that history where ever I want in my app and use it.

Comment: Seems that my app is so light weight, that I only need history in `ConfirmComponent ` and it can just access it from props without importing anything

Comment: Then my suggestion will be to just use BrowserRouter component from react-router-dom. And reduce redundant code. You don't need to create your own history object.